# Asset Pricing and Stochastic Discount Factor: Do well-informed investors only buy efficient portfolios?

Tags: finance, stochastic

I'm currently dealing with the following question:

**In Asset Pricing, well-informed investors know about the concept of the efficient frontier. Does this mean that they only invest in portfolios that lie on this efficient frontier?** I have that

$E[R^i]=R^f - \rho_{m, R^i} \sigma[R^i]\frac{\sigma[m]}{E[m]}$

where $R^i$ is the return of an asset i, $m$ is the stochastic discount factor therefore $\rho_{m, R^i}$ is the correlation between the stochastic discount factor and asset i, $\sigma[R^i]$ is the standard deviation of asset i, $\sigma[m]$ is the standard dev. of the SDF and $E[m]$ is the expected value of the SDF.

My thoughts: I know that assets that are located on the efficient frontier contain no unsystematic risk and are perfectly correlated with the stochastic discount factor (those on the upper part of the frontier have a correlation of -1 with the SDF and therefore carry maximum returns at maximum risk, those on the lower part of the frontier have a correlation of +1 with the SDF and therefore represent an optimal insurance against fluctuations in consumption. Generally, it would make sense to only invest in assets that lie on the efficient frontier as they are efficient, but on the other hand, I do not fully understand whether it can make sense to invest in an inefficient portfolio in order to achieve something that lies between the "maximum risk" and "perfect insurance" extremes I just described...can anyone help?

Comment: I think you made a small mistake in your comments. The efficient frontier is what you obtain what you choose portfolio weights that maximize returns, subject to a given level of risk. Conversely, it's the upper part of the minimal variance frontier defined by minimizing risk for any given level of returns... It's not maximual return and risk.

Comment: It seems to me that investors who only care about their wealth and face fixed investment opportunities (let's call them Markowitz investors) "only invest  in portfolios that lie on the Efficient Frontier". Once we consider investors who also care about hedging their consumption we must adopt a new and broader view. Such investors may (for above mentioned hedging purposes) hold assets not on the efficient frontier. Also, in R.C. Merton's ICAPM (if you have studied it) investors may hold long term bonds to hedge against fluctuations in the short term risk free rate (assumed fixed by Markowitz).